# Nested Loops Silverstripe 3.2

Tags: php, loops, nested, silverstripe

I'm having some issues getting nested loops to function how I would expect.
Here is some code.
If I write the following The output I get is XX YY XX YY

```
    <% loop PassengerType %>
        XX
            <% loop TourPricing %>
                    YY
            <% end_loop %>
    <% end_loop %> <!-- This out puts XX YY XX YY -->
```

However if I cut the code and remove the nested loops I get XX XX YY YY YY - Which is what i would expect as i have 2 PassengerType and 3 TourPricing

```
<% loop PassengerType %>
   XX
<% end_loop %>  
<% loop TourPricing %>
    YY
<% end_loop %> <!-- This outputs XX XX YY YY YY -->
```

What I really need is for it to do what I expect and with the first block of code output XX YY YY YY XX YY YY YY. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `$Up` to your nested loop e.g:

```
 <% loop PassengerType %>
        XX
            <% loop $Up.TourPricing %>
                    YY
            <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/templates/common_variables/#up

Comment: Awesome. I guess that was looking for a TourPricing array or similar inside the PassengerType Object and not finding it. Thanks again!